# Should we use "man" or "woman" to describe someone who identifies with female, but with male sexual physical appearance?

Tags: word-choice, gender-politics, social-gender

Inspired by [a recent gender-noun controversy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/529), I wonder how to properly address someone with obvious male sexual physical appearance, but who is insisted on being called a "she" ( probably because that's the sex that "she" feels should be associated with since birth, physical appearance regardless).

My concern specifically boils down to whether we should call "her" a man or or woman.

**"She is a man"**, or, **"She is a woman"**

Which one is correct?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question for English Language & Usage. We here are not the arbiters of gender trends, etiquette, or what to do in embarrassing situations, nor should we be relied on to speculatively parse all present and future uses of pronouns in all situations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because determining who is or is not male or female is not an ability this site possesses, nor should it be.

Comment: This question is not specific to English.

Comment: May I know where to ask this question , if this is not an appropriate forum?

Comment: This is an awfully trollish question for someone who's been around SE so long.

Comment: I'd suggest IPS, but first read up on their guidelines to know for certain whether it is on-topic or not. Feel free to include a link back to this page if you think that will help.

Comment: I'll also add, placing italics around *feels* is borderline rudeness. Luckily, this problem does not exist online because avatars and usernames can all be falsified. I might even be a 65-year-old Hungarian professor of Astronomy for all the world knows (just making a point).

Comment: @Mari-LouA, _placing italics around *feels* is borderline rudeness_ -- are we taking the whole thing a bit too far in terms of political correctness?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It's invalidating someone's right to say they belong to one gender or not. I did say "borderline" and @shoover said it was an "awfully  trollish question". I think, more than anything else,  I was trying to explain to myself why the question could be seen as "trollish".

Comment: @shoover.. so, I'm supposed to refer to other people correctly in terms of gender-noun, according to how they want to be referred to, but sometimes I am unsure. In order to not offend them, I ask on how I should appropriately refer them should a situation arises, and then my question is judged trollish.

Comment: Finally, the impetus behind the question comes from a post that explains why a moderator was fired/let go/dismissed by Stack Overflow. The *real* controversy revolves around the use of the  gender-neutral pronoun "they", which is also called the *singular they*, so you're misrepresenting the post you linked to in your question.  It is incorrect to call it a  "gender-noun" controversy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I might not be correct in using some terms- but isn't this the whole purpose of an English Q&A site, so that I can use some help? If I was already so good and I knew how to use all the terms correctly, then I wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place. Why do people have to nitpick and also assume that I ask the question in bad faith?

Comment: @Graviton Assuming you're asking in earnest, then you could introduce yourself and say, "Hi, I'm Graviton, and my pronouns are they/they" (or she/her or he/him or however you wish to be called in the third person). And probably they will respond in kind. But this is more an an interpersonal problem, and indeed has already been [asked and answered](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/1536/1970) on IPS. Related questions: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6481/1970 and https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/1099/1970 and https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/22065/1970

Comment: @shoover good links!

Comment: Upon rereading the question I felt that it was not clear enough. I've edited the question hopefully it's clearer this time.

Answer (score 6):

In the English language, as in others, any word depends on context: a word is *not* something like a physical object, so it is never linked entirely to a definite physical property or being. Similarly, several seemingly contradictory words can still in some way apply to the same thing.

Provided that this person is being serious, I think the only polite thing to do is to honour her request. The more masculine her appearance is, though, the less people will judge you if you slip from time to time. So try to do your best without getting nervous around her.

Comment: Well, I’d avoid taking this question too lightly given the mess that’s going on right now on SE just for “alleged misusage  of personal pronouns.”